# How do I force a 301 http status code using the redirect tag?

Tags: templating, redirect, tag

Using Craft's [`redirect`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/redirect) template tag creates a redirect with a 302 (Moved Temporarily) http status code. How can I force a 301 (Moved Permanently) status code?

Answer (score 4):

Although it is (as of today) not yet documented, looking through the [redirect twig extension](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/etc/templating/twigextensions/Redirect_TokenParser) revealed that the [`redirect`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/redirect) tag can accept a second parameter for the http status code. So forcing a 301 is done as follows:

```
{% redirect 'pricing' 301 %}
```

I've sent a request to P&T to add this to the docs.