# Can the HTTP status be set with the redirect tag

Tags: redirect

Although undocumented, according to this answer [How do I force a 301 http status code using the redirect tag?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/8248/how-do-i-force-a-301-http-status-code-using-the-redirect-tag/8249#8249) adding a 301 parameter to the redirect tag should change the status. I am using this but am still getting a 302 status.

```
{% redirect entry.getChildren().first().url 301 %}
```

Should this work to create a 301?

Answer (score 3):

That should work fine.  I just did a test in a simple template with:

```
{% redirect "http://google.com" 301 %}
```

And I can see it's a proper 301 redirect.  Try clearing your browser's cache?

Comment: The redirect function is from Yii. Documentation can be found here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#redirect-detail