# Redirecting with http status code doesn't render template

Tags: templating, redirect

**TL;DR**

Is there a way to redirect with a status code and have the correct template load with the correct status code?

---

I have template code which looks like this:

```
{% if slug is defined %}
 {% set entry = craft.entries.section('foobar').slug(slug).first() %}
 {% if not entry.editable %}
    {% redirect 403 %}
 {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

This works fine and redirects to the `403` template, but the problem is that is just redirects (changes the url) to `/403` with a status code of `302`

So [I followed from this question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/8248/how-do-i-force-a-301-http-status-code-using-the-redirect-tag) and used the second parameter to set the status code like so:

```
{% redirect 403 403 %}
```

Which sets the status code fine but now my 403 template doesn't load. If I try it with `404` the same problem applies.

When I go to a `404` page which is handled by Craft (no redirect tag) then the status code is set correctly and my `404` template loads just fine.

Is there a way to redirect with a status code and have the correct template load with the correct status code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{% exit 403 %}` seems to be the answer! Seems so obvious now... *facepalm*